# Как максимально обезопасить загрузку файлов на сервер?

Tags: php, fileupload, безопасность

Разрабатываю [файлообменник](http://putit.ru). just for fun. 
Но остро стал вопрос безопасности, постоянно пытаются загрузить туда php скрипты. 
Я, конечно же, фильтрую тип данных, но почему-то кажется, что все равно это очень дырявая штука. Что посоветуете почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Код свой :D Искать дыры и устранять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант — вообще не храните файлы в htdocs, и используйте nginx с [X-Accel-Redirect и internal location](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile). Заодно, так будет удобно учитывать каждое скачивание.

Да и загружать файлы будет удобно через nginx'овский [upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html). Тогда всем тяжелым вводом-выводом будет заниматься nginx, а скрипты будут только получать «закачали файл, лежит там-то, дальше сами раскладывайте как надо», а встроенная в модуль считалка MD5/SHA-1 позволит избавляться от дубликатов.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда полезно посмотреть, как это сделали другие. В современном мире существует масса "файловых помоек", далеко ходить не надо, например, LetitBit. Я тоже как-то пытался залить PHP-файл. Но, как оказалось, Letitbit закидывает этот файл(да и вообще все файлы) к себе в глубины и генерирует для них уникальную закодированную ссылку. Плюс ко всему он создает HTML-файл, из которого невозможно навредить серверу(ну да=) ) и записывает в него закодированную ссылку на твой php-Файл. Вот и все.

Comment: К себе в глубины - это за пределы public_html?

Comment: Нет конечно же) как же к ним тогда получить доступ.